# Set-ADuser -Identity extensionattribute not working

Tags: powershell, active-directory, attributes, bulk

I can't get this to work, don't understand it because it works on a single user. Is it not possible to use a variable with the cmdlet `Set-ADuser` ?

I want to change extensionattributes from a csv or textfile.

**This is my script:**

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$users = Import-Csv C:\csv.csv
Set-ADUser -Server servername -Identity $users -Replace @{extensionAttribute12="TEST"}
```

**I am getting this error:**

> Set-ADUser : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type
>   'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser' required by parameter
>   'Identity'. Specified method is not supported.

Comment: For both answers given, you need to specify what is in the `C:\csv.csv` file. Read about the [Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/set-aduser?view=win10-ps#required-parameters) parameter to see if the csv indeed contains any of the acceptable values.

Answer (score 0):

`users` is an array.
Try below code:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$users = Import-Csv C:\csv.csv
foreach($user in $users)
{
    Set-ADUser -Server servername -Identity $user -Replace @{extensionAttribute12="TEST"}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am getting this error now (also by TobyU)

Set-ADUser : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:13 char:5

Comment: Can you paste here some sample rows from csv file?
Also replace `Set-ADUser` line with below 
`Set-ADUser -Server servername -Identity $user -extensionAttribute12 "TEST"`

Answer (score 0):

`Import-Csv` returns an array of your csv rows and therefore, `Set-ADUser` needs to be used within a loop of those rows.

```
$users = Import-Csv C:\csv.csv
foreach($user in $users) {
    Set-ADUser -Server servername -Identity $user -Replace @{extensionAttribute12="TEST"}
}
```